# Azure Web Site with Django 500 Error

Tags: django, azure

I've spent over 8 hours trying to get this Django site up and running on an Azure Website. I've nearly thrown in the towel would really appreciate some help.

So far I have tried numerous methods and followed different tutorials, but they have all yielded the same result. Here is the most recent tutorial I have followed: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/

Now that my site is "up", I am seeing a 500 error for all requests. Here is the error in the log:

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during
   the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which mo
  dule handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this
  error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for t
  he Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incor
  rectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site o
  r application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to u
  se this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .
  NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct
   and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the ev
  ent logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the p
  ermissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if th
  e request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to tra
  ck failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creatin
  g a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show IIS logs? Have you tried to deploy empty Django project?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got it working by settings up a new django project from the azure gallery and changed some configs and such.

Edit: The configs I updated was just the name of my app. In my case I also updated the database config with the database I wanted to use in `settings.py`.

The lesson learned from this is that it is easier to initialize the app from Azure's "Create from gallery" feature, and then pull down the source and modify it via ftp or git to achieve the desired project structure/naming.

Comment: Dude, can you specify what configs and stuff you changed?

Comment: No changes to config listed: -1